# import MySQL database dump from .txt file

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, iis-7, joomla

I have a Joomla database that was dumped into a `.txt` file on an appache server using the command:-

```
mysqldump -u admin --opt -p passwd > private/alexthekiddb.txt
```

How do import that into a new MySQL database on my IIS server so I can attempt a conversion from Joomla to Wordpress.

I can use phpmyadmin or the MySQL builtin command line tool.

I already have a 2nd new database created with the same name and user (and PW) as the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, just running `mysql private/alexthekiddb.txt`  or `mysql < private/alexthekiddb.txt` should be enough. Hence, such dump files are usually suffixed `.sql`

Of course, you should have a MySQL server on the target machine (IIS thing).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.   I've since relocated the txt file from the apache server to my IIS server and have it in the website (that I'm trying to set up) directory in a folder called JOOMLA.
What command would I use to import that into a database for this Windows/ISS server?

Do you want an excerpt of the file so see the syntax?

Comment: OK, I have figured out how to do the import (had to run from OS command line, not MySQL command line).  Now I get the following errors (after a while)...  `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 142: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  ordering int(11) NOT NULL default '0',' at line 9`

Comment: I found that the error I mentioned was caused by the Joomla DB using 'reserved' words as column names...
To fix, I had to add `SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES'; ` to the start of the txt dump, then replace instances of **option** with **"option"**.  Likewise with **fulltext**.
The import then worked OK, and I have now migrated the database from Joomla to Wordpress.  Now there is just CSS cleanup and tweaking.